# Memoising a function over Unboxed Vectors causes it to hang

Tags: haskell

I'm playing with Vectors and Unboxed Vectors, with a fairly simple program. I'm enumerating all integers whose only factors are 2,3 & 5.

I thought I'd try memoising it over `Data.Vector` which worked and was super easy. So I thought I'd try `Data.Vector.Unboxed`. 
However, it hangs when z is `[0..5]`, but not when z is `[0..4]` and I'm not sure why. 
The difference between the two is that `5` involves a mutually  recursive call.

What's going wrong here?

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as UV

memoisingCandidateUV :: UV.Vector Bool
memoisingCandidateUV = UV.map isCandidateUV z

isCandidateUV :: Int -> Bool
isCandidateUV 0 = False
isCandidateUV n
    | n2r == 0 = n2q == 1 || memoisingCandidateUV UV.! n2q
    | n3r == 0 = n3q == 1 || memoisingCandidateUV UV.! n3q
    | n5r == 0 = n5q == 1 || memoisingCandidateUV UV.! n5q
    | otherwise = False
    where
      (n2q, n2r) = n `quotRem` 2
      (n3q, n3r) = n `quotRem` 3
      (n5q, n5r) = n `quotRem` 5
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All unboxed containers are deep-strict, which means you can't use them for lazy memoisation: before *any* element is accessible as memoised, you have to have *all of them* evaluated.

As to why this is so: when you have a normal lazy thunk in Haskell, it's the *box* that carries this information about that *the value is not yet in NF right now, but to make it so you can execute this piece of code*. After that's been done the box is basically just a pointer to the result.

That's a great help in many situations, but it's not for free memory- or performance-wise: that's precisely the overhead which unboxed containers remove, by *directly* storing the result information in a tight array.

Comment: Why are unboxed containers deep-strict? I believe I understand why, but it'd be useful to hear it from someone who actually knows.

Answer (score 6):

In this specific case (all recursive calls are to smaller indices, and `n` can be reconstructed from the already-computed vector), you can use [constructN](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.11.0/docs/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html#v%3aconstructN) (it works iteratively rather than relying on laziness):

```
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as UV

memoisingCandidateUV :: UV.Vector Bool
memoisingCandidateUV = UV.constructN 100 isCandidateUV

isCandidateUV :: UV.Vector Bool -> Bool
isCandidateUV vec = result
  where
    n = UV.length vec

    result
      |   n == 0 = False
      | n2r == 0 = n2q == 1 || vec UV.! n2q
      | n3r == 0 = n3q == 1 || vec UV.! n3q
      | n5r == 0 = n5q == 1 || vec UV.! n5q
      | otherwise = False

    (n2q, n2r) = n `quotRem` 2
    (n3q, n3r) = n `quotRem` 3
    (n5q, n5r) = n `quotRem` 5
```

Comment: Nice! Though I suppose this largely voids any performance advantage over boxed vectors?

Comment: It doesn't copy the vector at every iteration (if this is your suspicion); it passes a slice of an `unsafeFreeze` of the already-constructed mutable vector to the builder function, which is actually safe because that slice won't be mutated further ([Source](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-0.10.11.0/docs/src/Data-Vector-Generic.html#constructN)).